# What setup allows a Windows 7 client to use OS X 10.6.7 server VPN with L2TP?

Tags: windows, vpn, osx-server

I'm trying to get my Windows 7 laptop to connect to my OSX server VPN via L2TP. I understand that Windows 7 has some issues with NAT-T and I was wondering if anyone has a fix for this. Or has gotten this combo to work.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of annoying but fairly painless to resolve with a small edit to the registry on windows 7: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926179/

Comment: Pretty sure Windows persists by being kind of annoying but fairly painless. ;)